# Integrating Microsoft teams into my windows application

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a desktop app to which I want to integrate `Microsoft Teams`.
Does Teams provides an API for the integration.I read few articles but they all explained how to create apps in Teams and use of `Microsoft Graph API` to get information about Teams/channel etc.

Could someone help me with this, if they had any solution.

few of my finding on the internet:
https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2017/04/microsoft-actively-working-on-a-teams-api/
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16972258-developer-api-to-read-create-teams-and-channels-in?page=2&per_page=20

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct ways of accomplishing this:

- Using the Microsoft Graph API to create/read/write information. Currently the only thing we support is the ability to add a team to an existing Office 365 Group, the ability to create and read channels within a Team, and to post a message to a team/channel. We are adding more APIs, including the ability to read messages from a channel, but it's not available yet (and we don't have a public ETA). The ability to read and write channel messages from a channel should allow you do what you want.
- Controls that you can embed in an application that read/write the data for you. That's a common developer request and we will deliver that eventually, but it's further out.

Comment: Thank you very much Bill, I thought there is no API available at all to integrate teams with my desktop app. Bill I want the app to behave the way desktop team client behaves such as `real-time communications support (audio, video, and content sharing) for team meetings, group calling and private one-on-one calls` rather just `create/read/write team/channels` etc into teams. Is it possible with the existing Graph API ?

Comment: Not yet, but it's a common request and we'll get to it eventually, especially because it's part of converging with Skype for Business, which supports all of those things of course.

Comment: thanks Bill, your comments really helped to do my job. Bill one small issue with beta version of Graph API. I am able to access teams/groups of my organization but when I try to get the channels inside it by calling the API using _https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/channels_ it throughs me with an exception saying **Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).** any thoughts on this.

Comment: There should be a "/" between `groups` and `{id}` - e.g. this works in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) - `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/channels`.

Comment: thanks for replying Bill, when I access the link given by you in your comments above I get the error as: {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "dbd1f607-0bcd-4463-9090-5c1da90012c5",
      "date": "2018-01-23T09:57:14"
    }
  }
}

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT so is it done yet? I have been googling and cannot see any way to embed Teams into my App still!